# Reinstall /boot/<kernel> files through apt-get?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, kernel, apt-get

I was doing some maintenance and a script got away from me. I managed to delete the latest kernel files from `/boot` (actually, all the kernel files, including the old ones).

I need to re-install the missing kernel files. They are:

- `abi-3.2.0-72-generic`
- `config-3.2.0-72-generic`
- `vmlinuz-3.2.0-72-generic`
- `System.map-3.2.0-72-generic`

How can I use `apt-get` to reinstall the kernel files? Is it sufficient to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.2.0-72-generic` followed by `sudo update-grub2`? Or will I be missing a critical step?

Comment: @mdpc - Perfect, thanks. I have not run any commands yet. I wanted to double check first. There's no sense in making a bad situation worse.

Comment: ok....I made an answer out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be ok....

BTW, I'm pretty sure that grub will not be necessary if you install from the pre-packaged situation for the distribution as I believe that grub is performed as part of the package.

Of course, you problem will be if the package is still available.